# Some Icons Don't Show Up When Running in Server/Client Mode

Tags: emacsclient, mode-line, server, icons

I am writing my own config from scratch in emacs. It's not a very complicated config so far. I have installed `all-the-icons` font. It works just fine when I launch emacs directly and start working in it. This is how I see the left icons on my doom-modeline

[image]

But if I run an and emacs daemon and connect to it via a client. This is what I see. The icon for evil mode is replaced by some random character. What am I missing here?

[image]

BTW, the same problem does not occur if I open emacs normally, then run server-start and then launch the client.